# Resultados no se muestran en google con sitemap dinámico

Tags: php

Buenas,

Ayer estuve trabajando para crear un sitemap dinámico, para ello cree un fichero llamado `sitemap.php` y en el .htaccess añadí esta línea para que en vez de el fichero sitemap.xml me buscase el sitemap.php:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap\.php [L]
```

Por otra parte la estructura del sistema, al ser una web dinámica, la he creado con el siguiente código:

```
    <?php

header('Content-type: application/xml');
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
echo "<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
        xmlns:news='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9'>";

$bd_config = array(
    'basedatos' => 'XboxOne',
    'usuario' => 'root',
    'pass' => ''
    );

    require 'admin/config.php';

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['password'] );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        header ('Location: error.php');
        echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
        die();
    }



    $hoy = getdate();

    $fecha_hoy = $hoy['year'] . "-" . $hoy['mon'] . "-" . $hoy['mday'];

    echo "<url>";
      echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/</loc>";
      echo "<lastmod>" . $fecha_hoy . "</lastmod>";
      echo "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>";
      echo "<priority>1</priority>";
    echo "</url>";

    echo "<url>";
      echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/pagina_principal_precios.php</loc>";
      echo "<lastmod>" . $fecha_hoy . "</lastmod>";
      echo "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>";
      echo "<priority>1</priority>";
    echo "</url>";

    echo "<url>";
      echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/contacto.php</loc>";
      echo "<priority>0.8</priority>";
    echo "</url>";

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM listado_precios ORDER BY Agregado DESC");
    $statement->execute();
    $ultimo_juego = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo "<url>";
      echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/listado_precios.php</loc>";
      echo "<lastmod>" . substr($ultimo_juego[0]['Agregado'],0,10) . "</lastmod>";
      echo "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>";
      echo "<priority>1</priority>";
    echo "</url>";

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM retrocompatibles_360 ORDER BY Agregado DESC");
    $statement->execute();
    $ultimo_juego_360 = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo "<url>";
      echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/xbox360.php</loc>";
      echo "<lastmod>" . substr($ultimo_juego_360[0]['Agregado'],0,10) . "</lastmod>";
      echo "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>";
      echo "<priority>1</priority>";
    echo "</url>";

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM retrocompatibles_360 WHERE retro = 1 ORDER BY Agregado DESC");
    $statement->execute();
    $ultimo_juego_360_retro = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo "<url>";
      echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/retro.php</loc>";
      echo "<lastmod>" . substr($ultimo_juego_360_retro[0]['Agregado'],0,10) . "</lastmod>";
      echo "<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>";
      echo "<priority>1</priority>";
    echo "</url>";

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM listado_precios ORDER BY Agregado DESC");
    $statement->execute();
    $ultimo_juego = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo "<url>";
      echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/DWG.php</loc>";
      echo "<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>";
      echo "<priority>1</priority>";
    echo "</url>";


    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM art ORDER BY fecha_publicacion");
    $statement->execute();
    $articulos = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach ($articulos as $articulo) {
        echo "<url>";
          echo "<loc>http://www.laXtore.com/noticias.php?ID=" . $articulo['ID'] . "</loc>";
          echo "<news:news>";
            echo "<news:publication>";
              echo "<news:name>LaXtore</news:name>";
              echo "<news:language>es</news:language>";
            echo "</news:publication>";
            echo "<news:genres>Tecnología, Xbox One, videojuegos, videogames</news:genres>";
            echo "<news:publication_date>" . substr($articulo['fecha_publicacion'],0,10) . "</news:publication_date>";
            echo "<news:title>" . $articulo['titulo'] . "</news:title>";
            echo "<news:keywords>" . str_replace(",", ";",$articulo['etiquetas']) . "</news:keywords>";
          echo "</news:news>";
        echo "</url>";
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM listado_precios ORDER BY Agregado DESC");
    $statement->execute();
    $todos_juegos_xbox_one = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach ($todos_juegos_xbox_one as $Xbox_one) {
        echo "<url>";
          echo "<loc>http://www.laxtore.com/single.php?ID=" . $Xbox_one['ID'] . "</loc>";
          echo "<lastmod>" . substr($Xbox_one['Agregado'],0,10) . "</lastmod>";
          echo "<priority>0.8</priority>";
        echo "</url>";
    }

echo "</urlset>";

?>
```

Posteriormente subí el fichero con la herramienta de Google pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> Tu sitemap parece ser una página HTML. un formato de sitemap
>   compatible.

Anoche publiqué una nueva noticia pero todavía no aparece en los resultados de Google, ni siquiera metido directamente el título de la noticia y la web.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Se que quizás no va al caso pero `single.php?ID=940 or ""=""` necesita ser arreglado :D

Comment: @HectorSeguro no veo eso en el código. el número se carga de forma dinámica.

Comment: Lee bien que parece una url.